# How can I use Graph data structure to generate route with exact distance using Google API in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, graph

I need help with my final CS Project. Basically, I have to write an Android app that the user can specify a starting location and distance desired. It is going to generate a route that is exactly the distance of the input that the user can walk/ run and brings the user back to the starting location, using the Graph data structure and Google API.

I have my Google map and Android app but I’m not sure where to start with storing data using Graph ( I'm not sure if I should even use this data structure) and how to calculate the distance input. Any bits of advice/ help will be appreciated!

Comment: There is already algorithms that generates polylines which are basically routes from one point to another.   You can use that algorithm to draw the route.  Google API can also help you calculate the distance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay your question is very tricky but still let me answer from what I got.
Use google map api, google places api, place picker or id  and google maps json api for routes and distance.

```
let's take an example like you want walk or run 4kms from your places and comeback.
Case 1: if you want to opt for the same route from which you went to come back.
        like you went from a-b then again you are coming bak from b-a.
        for this case you can use Google maps geofencing and get the place inside a minimum raidus and make an algo to get the distance from your places.
 if teh distance is half of the distance from your places then pick the most approximate place.
     Use google maps json to get the places distance and google place picker for the location of nearby location object.

Case2: If you donot want to come from the same route through which you went 
by, then select the nearest location object and get the longest route and follow
 the same algo and procedure to get the distance.
```